# Unity shader set to GameObject position

Tags: unity, c#

I have a shader with acts like a magnifying glass that I downloaded and I have to attach to the camera scene.

My issue with this I want it in the same fixed position as the sprite but being attached to the camera when I changed the screen size for different devices it wonders to the upper right of the screen.

I am completely new to shaders so I and their scripts so I am not sure if this can be done.

```
private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest)
{
    if (mtrl == null || mtrl.shader == null || !mtrl.shader.isSupported)
    {
        enabled = false;
        return;
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) || !detectMouseButtonDown)
    {
        mtrl.SetFloat("_Radius", radius);
        mtrl.SetVector("_Mouse", new Vector4(740, 480, 0));
        mtrl.SetFloat("_Distortion", distortion);
        mtrl.SetFloat("_ScaleArea", scaleArea);
        if(isMagnifyingGlass)
        {
            mtrl.EnableKeyword("IS_MAGNIFYING_GLASS");
        }
        else
        {
            mtrl.DisableKeyword("IS_MAGNIFYING_GLASS");
        }
        if(warpType == WarpType.POW)
        {
            mtrl.EnableKeyword("WARP_TYPE_POW");
            mtrl.DisableKeyword("WARP_TYPE_EXP2");
        }
        else
        {
            mtrl.DisableKeyword("WARP_TYPE_POW");
            mtrl.EnableKeyword("WARP_TYPE_EXP2");
        }
        Graphics.Blit(src, dest, mtrl, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Graphics.Blit(src, dest);
    }
}
```

Shader:

```
Shader "Hidden/MagnifyingGlassFisheyeWarpImageEffect"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Always

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0
            #pragma multi_compile WARP_TYPE_POW WARP_TYPE_EXP2
            #pragma multi_compile _ IS_MAGNIFYING_GLASS

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 scrPos : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            float2 _Mouse;
            float _Radius;
            float _Distortion;
            float _ScaleArea;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.scrPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float4 c = 0;
                float2 uv = i.scrPos.xy/i.scrPos.w;
                float2 mousePos = _Mouse.xy / _ScreenParams.xy;
                float wh = _ScreenParams.y / _ScreenParams.x;
                uv.y *= wh;
                mousePos.y *= wh;
                if(length(uv - mousePos) <= _Radius)
                {
                    uv -= mousePos;
#if defined(IS_MAGNIFYING_GLASS)
                    float newLength = _ScaleArea * _Distortion;//_ScaleArea * pow(length(uv) / _Radius,  _Distortion);
#else
#if defined(WARP_TYPE_POW)
                    float newLength = _ScaleArea * pow(length(uv) / _Radius,  _Distortion);
#endif
#if defined(WARP_TYPE_EXP2)
                    float newLength = _ScaleArea * exp2(length(uv) / _Radius * _Distortion);
#endif
#endif
                    uv *= newLength;
                    uv += mousePos;
                }
                uv.y /= wh;

                c = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);
                return c;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what it looks like over the gold selector. It is in the correct position.

[image]

Now if I change the screen size for a different device the magnifying effect has shifted to the right

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what you want it to look like, and what it looks like instead? We'll also need to see the shader code.

Comment: I have added the shader coder. I am getting screenshots now. I have it set to `WARP_TYPE_EXP2`

Comment: instead of use image effect try to use sprite shader.with grabpassing you can grab background of sprite and magnify it.